# python fabric how to start process on remote machine

Tags: python, linux, fabric

all
   I am using fabric to deploy my python job. the python project contains such an shell named 'run_fetchserver.sh' to control start/stop of the process.

```
fetch_path=$PROJECT_PATH
if [ $1 = start ]
then
    psid=`ps aux | grep "fetch_server" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l`
    if [ $psid -gt 1 ]
        then
        echo "fetchserver is running!"
        exit 0
    else
        pushd $fetch_path
            nohup python fetch_server.py >>start_fetchserver.log 2>&1 &
        popd
        echo "Start fetchserver service [OK]"
    fi
elif [ $1 = stop ];then
    pkill -f "fetch_server.py"
    echo "Stop fetch service [OK]"
elif [ $1 = restart ];then
    pkill -f "fetch_server.py"
    pushd $fetch_path
        nohup python fetch_server.py >>start_fetchserver.log 2>&1 &
    popd
    echo "Restart fetchserver service [OK]"
else
    echo "Usages: sh fetchserver server.sh [start|stop|restart]"
fi
```

This script runs well locally, But when I call it with fabric commands
    run('./run_fetchserver.sh restart')
The job is not started on remote machine at all. Why?

Comment: Did you copy script on remote computer? Did you try to run script manually on remote computer?

Comment: When a fabric task doesn't execute it usually produces an error, can you share that error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved at last.

I have changed only one line in my fabfile.py:

from

```
run('./run_fetchserver.sh restart')
```

to

```
run('./run_fetchserver.sh restart', pty=False)
```

Thus the program started successfully on remote machine.

Comment: I dont think this is a good solution in my opinion, i would rather use `supervisord` this does nothing if the app/server crashes. I dont know, i like supervisord :/